# Editing Location Not Updating Map

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have a list of transaction entries that includes location coordinates. Tapping on an entry in the list creates a view with a map and transactions details. Tapping on **Edit Location** within the detail view presents a form for a new address. Tapping **Save** returns to detail view with the new map and transaction details.

What I see occurring upon tapping **Save** is the details with the wrong (old) map. I am using a UIKit map because I want to allow the customer the option of the Apple standard three different maps views (Default, Transit, and Satellite). Returning to the transaction view and back to detail view then displays the correct view.

When using breakpoints to follow the flow, I see upon tapping a transaction entry calls to **MakeUIView** and **updateUIView** in MapView. Upon tapping **Save** in Edit Location only **updateUIView** is called. Detail view does appear to have the correct coordinates, it is just not calling makeUIView().

DetailView is called from HistoryView (transaction entry list)

```
struct DetailView: View {

    @ObservedObject var item: CurrTrans // use to refresh view

    @State private var mapType: MKMapType = .standard

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: item.entryLat,
            longitude: item.entryLong)
    }

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { g in

            VStack {
                ShowMap(item: item, coordinate: coordinate, mapType: mapType)
                   .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height * 0.68)
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)

                // show transaction details
                showData(g: g, item: item)

                Spacer()

                NavigationLink(destination: EditLocation(g: g, item: item)) {Text("Edit Location")}
                    .padding(.bottom, g.size.height * 0.01)
                    
            }
            .font(.subheadline)
            .navigationBarTitle("Transaction Details", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        } 
    }
}
```

```
struct EditLocation: View {

    var g: GeometryProxy
    var item: CurrTrans

    @ObservedObject private var lm = LocationManager()

    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    // persistant entry storage in coreData
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

    @State private var getStreet: String = ""
    @State private var getCity: String = ""
    @State private var getState: String = ""
    @State private var getCountry: String = ""

    @State private var invalidAddr: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ShowEntryDetails(item: item)

            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.55, height: g.size.height * 0.50)
 
                // get new address input
                GetFormEntry( getStreet: $getStreet, getCity: $getCity, getState: $getState, getCountry: $getCountry)

            } .navigationBarTitle(Text("Edit Transaction Location"), displayMode: .inline) // end zstack
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {

                    // prep address string for conversion to coordinates
                    let locStr = getStreet + "," + getCity + "," + getState + " " + getCountry

                    lm.getCoordinate(addressString: locStr) { coordinates, error  in

                        print("edit coordiantes = \(coordinates)")

                        if error == nil {
                            print(coordinates.latitude)
                            print(coordinates.longitude)

                            item.entryLat = coordinates.latitude
                            item.entryLong = coordinates.longitude

                            //item.address = getStreet + "\n" + getCity + " " + getState + "\n" + getCountry
                            item.entryCity = getCity
                            item.entryState = getState
                            item.entryCountry = getCountry

                            do {
                                try viewContext.save()
                            } catch {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                                // FIX: report error (Unable to Save Location Changes)
                            }
                            dismiss()

                        } else {
                            // Invalid address-- try again
                            invalidAddr = true

                            getStreet = ""
                            getCity = ""
                            getState = ""
                            getCountry = ""
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    Text ("Save")
                }.disabled(getStreet.isEmpty || getCity.isEmpty || getCountry.isEmpty)
                )
        }
        .alert("Invalid Address, Try Again", isPresented: $invalidAddr, actions: {
        })
    }
}


struct GetFormEntry: View {

    @Binding var getStreet: String
    @Binding var getCity: String
    @Binding var getState: String
    @Binding var getCountry: String

    enum Field: Hashable {
        case getStreet
        case getCity
        case getState
        case getCountry
    }

    @FocusState private var ckFocus: Field?

    let maxDscDigits = 40

    var body: some View {

        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Enter Transaction Address")) {
                TextField("Street Address", text: $getStreet)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.15))
                    .focused($ckFocus, equals: .getStreet)
                    .keyboardType(.default)

                // prevent pasting of non-valid text
                    .onChange(of: getStreet) {
                        let txt = $0
                        if dscAllowed(txt, maxDscDigits: maxDscDigits) {
                            getStreet = txt
                        } else {
                            getStreet = String(txt.dropLast())
                        }
                    } // end onChange

                TextField("City", text: $getCity)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.15))
                    .focused($ckFocus, equals: .getCity)
                    .keyboardType(.default)

                // prevent pasting of non-valid text
                    .onChange(of: getCity) {
                        let txt = $0
                        if dscAllowed(txt, maxDscDigits: maxDscDigits) {
                            getCity = txt
                        } else {
                            getCity = String(txt.dropLast())
                        }
                    } // end onChange

                TextField("State", text: $getState)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.15))
                    .focused($ckFocus, equals: .getState)
                    .keyboardType(.default)

                // prevent pasting of non-valid text
                    .onChange(of: getState) {
                        let txt = $0
                        if dscAllowed(txt, maxDscDigits: maxDscDigits) {
                            getState = txt
                        } else {
                            getState = String(txt.dropLast())
                        }
                    } // end onChange

                TextField("Country", text: $getCountry)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.15))
                    .focused($ckFocus, equals: .getCountry)
                    .keyboardType(.default)

                // prevent pasting of non-valid text
                    .onChange(of: getCountry) {
                        let txt = $0
                        if dscAllowed(txt, maxDscDigits: maxDscDigits) {
                            getCountry = txt
                        } else {
                            getCountry = String(txt.dropLast())
                        }
                    } // end onChange
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ShowMap: View {

    @ObservedObject var item: CurrTrans

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    var mapType: MKMapType

    @ObservedObject private var lm = LocationManager()

    var body: some View {

        // location services disabled?
        if item.entryLat == 0.0 && item.entryLong == 0.0 {
            VStack {

                Text("Map Not Available")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text("Location Services Disabled or Map Not Available")
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }

        } else {

            //Text("Before: \(item.entryLat) \(item.entryLong)")
            // we have a map so lets display it
            let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)

            MapView(region: region, mapType: mapType, coordinate: coordinate)

        }
    }
}


/*---------------------------------------
    Use UIKit map view to display the 3 map types
 ---------------------------------------*/
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @ObservedObject private var lm = LocationManager()

    let region: MKCoordinateRegion
    let mapType : MKMapType
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        // display a map pin
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        mapView.mapType = mapType
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        mapView.mapType = mapType
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Location Delegate, try to implement this instance method from [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager)

Hope it works for your problem.

Comment: I have a location manager with location delegate. To me, it appears that upon presentation of the new address the phone GPS has correctly determined the location coordinates. All my breakpoints around the map logic all show the correct coordinates for the new address. In fact upon exiting the detail view and returning draws the correct map.  So it seems like the problem is in generating the map. Do you want to see my LocationManager logic?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).